# Jenkins how to copy a report files from past 10 executions

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i am running a jenkins job which goes to a particular folder. In that folder there will be `build numbers like 1 to 80`.

I need to pick the last 10 executions, say from `80 to 70` . Open each folder and copy the report file from each folder to a particular location.

So hows that possible. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this plugin, it may be useful for you, it displays your test-case, test-class and test-package from the build reports in a organised table format.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Test+Results+Analyzer+Plugin

Comment: it wont help for my need